# Windows 8 causing hot CPU

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, overheating

As soon as I installed windows 8 my CPU began to overheat. How did I know this? Well my left leg started getting hot and my fans starting whirring like crazy.

I confirmed with OpenHardwareMonitor and also installed Sysinternals Process-Explorer to investigate. Well it turns out CPU usage is low, less than 4% (Except for System-Idle-Process, which I expect to be high when nothing else is running) and yet temperature is high!

As far as I can see from google, etc. other people have come across this, but there's no clear answer as to why and no fix.

I suspect it may be because Windows 8 isn't instructing my core i7-3610QM cpu to shift to an idle state. Before you ask, I've installed all the chipset drivers.

Has anyone come across this and fixed it?

Or does anybody know how to further investigate?

Comment: Have you tried killing the dust bunnies that live in your laptop.  Its unlikely Windows 8 is causing this problem.

Comment: Download CPU-z and check to see if your frequency is always at maxed/turbo-ed or if it calms down

Comment: `Well my left leg started getting hot...` This statement leads me to believe that you are suffocating the airflow of the cooling system by improperly setting it on your lap; and yes there is a proper way to set it on your lap.

Comment: Them dust bunnies are running all over the place. No seriously the laptop is clean (enough). MonkeyZeus as a preliminary answer to your 1st comment, yes the CPUs are running at around max (according to open hardware monitor) I'll get CPU-z and check too... ps what's the correct way on your lap?? as far away from the family jewels is my sentiment.

Comment: Laptops get hot. It happens. I would check the CPU temperature using a program like Speccy before jumping to the conclusion that it's "too hot" though. For an Intel processor anything over 70C is in the danger zone and could lead to system instability, spontaneous shutdowns, etc. Try to test it under full load... maybe you could open a game or something else demanding in the background while you monitor the temperature. The comment above about not suffocating the airflow is also an important point. Try setting your laptop down on a desk and tilting it up with a paperback book in the back.

Answer (score 0):

Normally a hot CPU would mean a highly active CPU but there may be an odd case where it could mean high I/O.

I personally came across this strange case myself on my work laptop last week. I downloaded Process Monitor and took a trace sample and saw that it was spending a good deal of time reading a 3gb inventory file. Like you, the CPU usage was low but the laptop was hot. Download Process Monitor, take a trace and go to Tools and count occurrences and see what is the most accessed file in the trace.